# Where do I properly place sqlite database so it wouldn't get removed on app update from appstore?

Tags: ios, sqlite, app-store

I am frightened to release my app using this technique to put the database on NSDocumentDirectory. what if I put on an update? will it get removed? users of the app might get really annoyed when the database will get overwritten and clear its contents?

do you think im doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html

> Files Saved During App Updates
>
> When a user downloads an app update, iTunes installs the update in a
>   new app directory. It then moves the user’s data files from the old
>   installation over to the new app directory before deleting the old
>   installation. Files in the following directories are guaranteed to be
>   preserved during the update process:
>
> ```
> <Application_Home>/Documents
>
> <Application_Home>/Library
> ```
>
> Although files in other user directories may also be moved over, you
>   should not rely on them being present after an update.

Comment: So its safe to put my db file on Documents?

Comment: if it contains user data, yes -- it wont get overriden

Comment: Thats what i want to hear! now I can launch my app! thanks :)